# CLI function: How to run many flags in the same command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code with 3 functions that test 3 functions in another file using argparse. I have a flag assigned to each of the test functions. One by one they run as expected.

```
 $python code_test.py -w
    words_containing passed
```

...where len_safe is the function l is assigned to.
-w is assigned to a function called words containing.
my goal is to have the following input:

```
 $python code_test.py -w -l
    len_safe passed
    words_containing passed
```

...Currently when I try this:

```
 $python code_test.py -u -l
    usage: HW3_test.py [-h] [-w WORDS] [-l LEN] [-u UNIQUE]
    HW3_test.py: error: argument -w/--words: expected one argument
```

The following is my code:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-w','--words',help='Words')
    parser.add_argument('-l','--len',help='len')
    parser.add_argument('-u','--unique',help='unique')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    elif args.words == "W" :
        if test_words_containing() == True:
            print('words_containing pass')
        else:
            print('words_containing fail')
    elif args.words == "l" :
        if test_len_safe() == False:
            print('len_safe fail')
        else:
            print('len_safe pass')
```

What would I need to change for the command line to accept multiple flags (the results can be in any order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flag is meant to be a Boolean value, and `argparse` by default adds arguments as a string. What you can do instead is to use `action='store_true'` when adding arguments.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-w','--words', action='store_true', help='Words')
parser.add_argument('-l','--len', action='store_true', help='len')
parser.add_argument('-u','--unique', action='store_true', help='unique')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.words:
    if test_words_containing() == True:
        print('words_containing pass')
    else:
        print('words_containing fail')
if args.len:
    if test_len_safe() == False:
        print('len_safe fail')
    else:
        print('len_safe pass')
```

Comment: I added your code in place of my first 4 lines posted above. However, when I now try any of the inputs in the command line I posted above, I either get no output or and error saying a certain flag was not identified. Any idea why?

Comment: `args.words` is now a Boolean value, so you need to use `if args.words:` instead of `if args.words == "W" :`, like I suggested in my code.